# How to make external css file apply to only one element

Tags: jquery, css

My site has a default css file called 'site.css'.

I'm using the datepicker of jquery and it has its own css file called 'jquery.css'.

When I import both of them at the header of the page, I find that the layout is messed up.

I'm wondering is it possible to make the jquery.css style only available to the calendar field in the page.

Actually, it's not jquery.css messing my layout. It's my site.css messing the layout of the popup calendar.

Comment: You're probably just going to have to edit the jquery.css file so that there aren't any conflicts in the selectors, you could use a container and prefix all of the selectors in jquery.css with that containers selector.

Comment: Is this the official jQuery UI datepicker or a third party plugin?

Answer (score 2):

1. Give your calendar field an id (if it doesn't already have one).
2. Go into the JQuery CSS file and take out the style for the datepicker.
3. Paste this style into your own 'site.css' file but under the id of your calendar field (so if your calendar field has the id `calendar` then use:

   `#calendar {
            // JQuery style code you want copied here
   }`

I don't see much point in loading a whole css style sheet for one field, much less coming up with some code to narrow its influence. Might as well strip out what you need and re-use it, crediting John Resig where you feel it's appropriate.

Comment: jquery's css file is kind of big. So I'm trying to avoid digging into it.

Comment: All the more reason not to include the entire file in your code, as you'll potentially just be adding unnecessary load time for very little pay-off. But I do understand that digging into it can seem kind of scary :-) Doing a Ctrl-F search in the file for `.ui-datepicker` will you get to the right place. JQuery UI is very organised so you could potentially extract that entire section for use in your own file.

Comment: It's more than the .ui-datepicker. 

I have a try and the popup calendar is a plain one with no style.

So I have to copy ui.icon ui.corner ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I add class name "site" to the container 'div' in site.css.

And add class="site" to the div on my page. Now everything looks good.

Thank you all.